# MySQL utf-8 not recognising special characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, mysql-workbench

Does anyone have any ideas why this is failing?

I have created a utf-8 table with a char3 primary key, and when inserting records into it with MySQL Workbench, it is failing to distinguish between A and Ä

We are using MySQL 5.1.73 and Workbench 6.3.10

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `citycode` char(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`citycode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLA');
INSERT INTO `test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLÄ');

Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to the database.
Executing:
INSERT INTO `trains4_copy`.`test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLA');
INSERT INTO `trains4_copy`.`test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLÄ');

ERROR 1062: 1062: Duplicate entry 'JLÄ' for key 'PRIMARY'
SQL Statement:
INSERT INTO `trains4_copy`.`test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLÄ')
```

Comment: Your charset may be utf8, but what is your collation set to for column `citycode`?

Comment: If you want `Ä=Æ`, then use utf8_german2_ci.  utf8_slovak_ci treats `Ä` as a letter that sorts after "az"; perhaps you want that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-binary-collations.html), store these types of charsets as binary.

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `citycode` char(3) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`citycode`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin;

INSERT INTO `test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLA');
INSERT INTO `test` (`citycode`) VALUES ('JLÄ');
```

try this [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=Bu3v38vtcj).

Comment: Thank you for this. It was the collation. I was using utf8_unicode_ci which did not work. When I changed it to utf8_bin, it worked.